# Is a vampire virus possible?

Tags: viruses

I want to make a vampire virus spread by sex and kissing. But, I’m not wanting to add anything unrealistic. I want the virus to originate from one rogue vampire from hell. Is this possible?

Comment: You have a very appropriate name

Comment: any colour is as possible as any other,  do you mean "rogue"?

Answer (score 1):

I think that this should be completely possible. [Herpes simplex](https://www.who.int/news-room/fact-sheets/detail/herpes-simplex-virus)  is a real-world example of a virus that can be spread by kissing or by sex. I don't see any reason for your vampire virus to behave differently (unless your vamps have dental hardware which inhibits kissing, but whatever, there's always sex).

If the virus starts with only one person it won't spread very quickly at first, but it should speed up after not-too-long as exponential growth kicks in (I'm sure that everyone will see the obvious real-world example for this point :( ).